# Separate selected UV map vertices from surrounding vertices

Tags: uv

How do I break the selected UV map from its surrounding vertices?

[image: UV selection image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the face and using *Select > Select Split* from the *Image Editor* header or the <kbd>Y</kbd> key, then drag to separate. This method doesn't require you changing the *Sticky Selection Mode*, but it does require that you separate *at least* one tri. This method does not work for separating a single point or edge.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in blender 2.8.x?

Comment: @PieterDeBie I couldn't find a menu entry for it but the same shortcut seems to work. Open the context menu with space and search for *Select Split*. After running the operation, press G and move the cursor.

Comment: "This method does not work for separating a single point or edge." Wait, so you can't cut a single UV edge in Blender? Is that what you're saying? Guess I'll just go back to importing/exporting between Maya for what should be a most basic and straightforward operation.

Answer (score 20):

Change the Sticky Selection Mode to Disabled in the bottom settings bar, then drag to separate the selection.

[image]

Comment: This function behaves oddly, it seems you have to select it _again_ even though it is already selected by default.

Comment: @iKlsR - this is working as intended, changing sticky mode wont change the existing selection, only new selection actions

Comment: @ideasman42 as it turns out, I was doing multiple tests with the same map, so it was on my end.