# Separate multiple faces UV

Tags: selection-tools, uv-image-editor

I can separate single faces in the UV editing mode. I disabled sync selection and sticky vertex selection. But when I select two faces in a group of joined faces, I can't separate them by pressing Y. I have blender 2.74.

How can I split a group of joined faces in the UV mode?

Comment: the same question have been asked before here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/separate-selected-uv-map-vertices-from-surrounding-vertices or I am have misunderstood your question. Pressing Y allow me to split any face from joining adject faces on the UV editor. Did you press G to move them apart after the split?

Comment: Good problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hit the** <kbd>G</kbd> **key** to move those faces.

After spliting the faces. You would be required to move it. The split operation does not automatically move the selected uv for you.